# Ubuntu 18.04 does not boot and hangs on power off, on new Vivobook:

Tags: ubuntu, bios, asus

I've bought new Asus Vivobook without OS. I've prepared bootable pendrive with Ubuntu 18.04 and I've gotten problem with installation - could not find SSD.

I've changed in BIOS a SATA option to AHCI and added set `pci=nomsi` in GRUB and managed to install on SSD.

Unfortunately the OS bahaves strangely. In most cases it won't boot completely or hangs on poweroff.

When it doesn't boot all the way after GRUB it hangs on a purple screen.

I have logs: https://pastebin.com/CKVGQhpA

Comment: In what way dose your computer not switch on?

Comment: In GRUB I press "Start Ubuntu" and I get purple empty screen and nothing else (no login etc.).

Comment: Respond by fixing the question.

Comment: I don't understand ?

Comment: There is an edit button on the question. Click it. Amend the question to include your comment. May it the best question that you can, so that some will be able to answer it.

Comment: Asus Vivobook S14 S430FN 18.04 - Intel firmware update required https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146431/no-possible-way-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-zenbook-ux433fn & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424764